# What does RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f mean?

Tags: apache, nginx, webserver

I had the following rule in the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,B,QSA]
```

Now I've switched to Nginx and I converted it to this: (Using an online website)

```
location ~ "^/([\s\S]*)$" {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$1;
}
```

It works in some cases, but it doesn't work exactly as expected. I mean `$_GET['id']` would be `Null` even when there is `?id=10` passed to the URL.

Now I'm trying to understand what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means to be able to convert it to Nginx config syntax. Any idea how can I convert it to Nginx exactly the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server converts the URL into a pathname for the requested file. This is stored in the variable `REQUEST_FILENAME`. The `RewriteCond` statement in your question asserts that this file exists. If the pathname does not exist as a file or directory, then the request is passed to `index.php`.

In Nginx, this is equivalent to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;` - the `$uri` term tests if the file exists, the `$uri/` term tests if the directory exists, and the final parameter is the action taken if both tests fail.

In Apache, the `QSA` flag in the `RewriteRule` ensures that the requested query string is also appended to the rewritten URL. Your `try_files` snippet isn't doing that! You are **replacing** the query string with `rt=$1`.

Try:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?rt=$1&$args;
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanations, I almost understood how Apache and Nginx work in this case.